Hot Chocolate GraphQL remote schema error handling and instrumentation
I do have several microservices which expose a GraphQL layer each. These microsevices call legacy HTTP APIs, and use an Error Filter for HttpClient, to catch HttpRequestExceptions, if the HTTP call towards the legacy services do fail for any reason, and to send a structured error message back. Also, ExecutionDiagnosticsEventListener is used for instrumentation.
There is a main proxy microservice, which uses GraphQL Remote Schema Stitching. This one does not expose a GraphQL layer directly, but aggregates GraphQL layers of the other microservices. There is a HTTP client for each of the GraphQL services.
I do have two issues:
1, Nor Error Filters nor ExecutionDiagnosticsEventListener is working for the proxy microservice. I want to send a meaningful error message for the front end, if any of the GraphQL microservices can not be reached for any reason (Service is down, for example). I can not catch HttpRequestExceptions with Error Filters nor log them in ExecutionDiagnosticsEventListener. I can see the HttpRequestExceptions in the console, but the error handling/logging code won't be called.
2, The error blocks returned by HotChocolate seems to be pretty inconsistent (Path property is in the Extension block sometimes, and the error block looks completely different for schema stitching). They look completely different based on which step of the GraphQL execution pipeline was the error arisen. There are many articles how to use Domain Errors for mutations, but not sure how to do a consistent error handling with consistent error messages for Queries and for unexpected events, like the HTTP client faliure.  The goal is to make front end to be able to process these error message blocks a consistent way, where all the required properties will be at the very same place.
GraphQL Remote Schema Stitching code, includes instrumentation:
services
    .AddHttpClient("GraphQLMicroservice1ClientName", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(GraphQLMicroservice1ClientAddress));

services
    .AddHttpClient("GraphQLMicroservice2ClientName", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(GraphQLMicroservice2ClientAddress));

services
    .AddHttpClient("GraphQLMicroservice3ClientName", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(GraphQLMicroservice3ClientAddress));

services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddDiagnosticEventListener<HttpDiagnosticEventListener>()
    .AddRemoteSchema(GraphQLMicroservice1ClientName)
    .AddRemoteSchema(GraphQLMicroservice2ClientName)
    .AddRemoteSchema(GraphQLMicroservice3ClientName)

Error Filter setup code:
serviceCollection.AddErrorFilter<HttpClientErrorFilter>();

I would expect both HttpClientErrorFilter and HttpDiagnosticEventListener to get called in case of an exception being thrown regarding the Http clients, but nothing happens, while I can see the exceptions in the console. This very same solution works for the Http clients in the GraphQL microservices. Remote schema stitching seems to ignore both of them.
